# Tell me what is wrong with this js code as I don't see it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate

So I'm using the http://tooltipsy.com/ jquery plugin and have trouble getting my animation to work.

**My code;**

```
<script src="{T_THEME_PATH}/js/jquery.tipsy.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
$("a").tipsy({
    show: function (e, $el) {
    $el.fadeIn(500);
    },
    content: '<em>Look ma</em>, my tooltip has <strong>HTML</strong>',
    delay: 200
});

$("img").tipsy({
    delay: 200,
    show: function (e, $el) {
        $el.fadeIn(500);
    },
    content: '<em>Look ma</em>, my tooltip has <strong>HTML</strong>'
});
// $("element").tipsy({gravity: jQuery.fn.tipsy.autoNS}); //old code remains, keep this intact. As a reference because this code works.
});
</script>
```

http://pastebin.com/0iXeV7Zi

I've loaded jquery in the footer and put said the code below the jquery being loaded. So no head code present but the .css file of tooltipsy ofc.

Google chrome shows no errors and the tooltip does show but without any sort of animation I defined.

The fadeIn animation doesn't seem to work and I don't know why, do you?

Comment: Paste the code in the question.

Comment: So what's {T_THEME_PATH}? And where does the main jquery lib get loaded?

Comment: It's probably not the cause of the problem, but you ought to have semicolons after each of your $().tipsy() calls - specifically lines 11 and 19 in the code snippet in the question. Worth a try.

Comment: @DaveJones that is the path of my theme, [link](http://phpbb.miscy.net/styles/rainbow/theme/js/jquery.tipsy.min.js) It gets loaded in the footer, no worries. There are no jquery not defined errors showing up. You can take a look if you want to.

Comment: @TedSales thanks for the hint, I fixed that in my code onsite and on here. It didn't solve my issue though.

Comment: As I suspected - never mind. I have no experience with this plugin but I'm sure someone who does will find your problem :)

Comment: Huh, I just tried this with your code and it works perfectly for me. I'm assuming you are including jQuery above the plugin? FWIW with the latest version of tooltipsy I had to call the `.tooltipsy()` method, `.tipsy()` threw an error.

Comment: Looking at the page http://phpbb.miscy.net/,  your trying to bind the tooltipsy to a and img before they loaded by another script.

Comment: @Johnathan you made me re-look this from a different angle and I managed to solve my issue thanks to you and the other guys here. I wouldn't have figured it out without you guys! Thanks a ton.